# How to fetch list using @ManyToMany relationship between the tables in Java + hibernate + panache repository

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, many-to-many, quarkus-panache

I have two entities created i.e., Person and Message and there is a @ManyToMany relationship between the tables. I am using Quarkus framework which supports PanacheRepository and Postgres DB.
My requirement is to fetch all the messages corresponds to a Person but I am getting below error :

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Person{...}] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]**

2023-05-12 11:19:21,285 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) HTTP Request to /persons/1/messages failed, error id: 59165c88-d7d9-470b-99f4-8ca3509f2960-1: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Person{id=1, name='abhishek', age=28}] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]
at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54)

Any suggestion/comments would be very helpful.

These are the entities:

```
@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "message_id")
    Long id;

    @Column
    String messageBody;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Person> person;
    ..................
    ..................

}

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="person_name")
    private String name;

    @Column
    private int age;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Message> messageList;
    .............................
    .............................
}
```

Repositories classes:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MessageRepository implements PanacheRepository<Message> {
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class PersonRepository implements PanacheRepository<Person> {
}
```

Resource class:

```
@Path("/persons")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class PersonResource {
    @Inject
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Inject
    MessageRepository messageRepository;

    @GET
    @Path("/{userId}/messages")
    public Response listAllMessagesOfAUser(Long userId) {
        Person person = personRepository.findById(userId);
        
        List<Message> messagesList = messageRepository.find("person", person).list();
        
        return Response.ok(messagesList).build();
    }
.............................................
}
```

I am first fetching the person using the userId and passing the obtained person object to fetch the list of message corresponding to that person.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue and fetch all messages for a user using the below query:

```
List<MessageEntity> messagesList = messageRepository.find("Select m from MessageEntity m Join m.personEntity p where p.id=?1", userId).list();
```